# Relational query for ParseUser not working

Tags: android, parse-platform, relational-database

Here is my inner query :

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> innerQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
innerQuery.whereMatches("username", "(" + searchText + ")", "i");
```

Here is my OuterQuery :

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("UserProfile");
query.include("profileId.userId");
query.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
query.whereEqualTo("relation", "Agent");
///query.whereMatchesQuery("profileId", innerQuery);
query.whereMatchesQuery("userId", innerQuery);
enter code here
```

**userId** is Pointer of _user in **UserProfile** class

Here is callback for query

```
  query.whereMatchesQuery("userId", innerQuery);
if (loadMore) {
  limit = limit + 15;
  query.setLimit(15);
} else
  query.setLimit(limit);
query.setSkip(skip);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  @Override
  public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {}
```

getting list size **Zero** from Parse

Answer (score 0):

Try `ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserProfile");`

Comment: Still not getting results.

Comment: What is this line `query.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());` - You mean the same `userId` like here `query.include("profileId.userId");` ?

Comment: No in ' query.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser())' is condition for getting required results and query.include("profileId.userId"); is used for getting profileid and userid columns data because  both are pointer to some other table userid points to _User table.

Comment: Update Your question with how Your Parse classes are build (only thing that matter) and what specifically You want to achieve.